# Entity Framework, application layers and separation of concerns

Tags: entity-framework, orm, architecture, entity-framework-4.1, separation-of-concerns

I'm using the Entity Framework 4.1 and ASP.Net MVC 3 for my application. MVC provides the presentation layer, an intermediate library provides the business logic and the Entity Framework sort of acts as the data layer I guess?

I could separate the Entity Framework code into a set of repository classes, or an appropriate variation thereof, whatever constitutes a worthwhile data layer, but I'm having trouble resolving a design problem I have.

If the multi-layered approach exists to help me keep concerns separated, then it stands to reason that my choice of data persistence should also not be a concern of the presentation layer. The problem is that by using the Entity Framework, I'm basically tightly coupling my application to the notion that entity changes are tracked and persisted automatically.

As such, let's say in a hypothetical world I found a reason not to use the Entity Framework and wanted to swap it out. A well-designed solution should allow me to do this at the appropriate layer and not have dependent layers affected, but because all code is being written with the knowledge that the data layer tracks object changes, I would only be able to swap out the Entity Framework for something that works in a similar fashion, for example nHibernate.

How do I get to use the Entity Framework but not need to write my code in a way that assumes that entity changes are being tracked by the data layer?

**UPDATE for those still wondering about this issue in their own scenarios:**
Ayende Rahien wrote a great article shooting down this whole argument:
http://ayende.com/blog/4567/the-false-myth-of-encapsulating-data-access-in-the-dal

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to continue this way you should give up programming job and go to study philosophy. Entity framework is abstraction of persistence and there is a rule of [Leaky abstraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaky_abstraction) which says that any non-trivial abstraction is to some degree leaky.

Agile methodologies come with really interesting phenomenon: Do not prepare for hypothetical situations. The most of the time it is just [Gold plating](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gold_plating_%28software_engineering%29). Each change has its cost. Changing persistence layer later in the project is costly but it is also very rare. From customer perspective there is no reason to pay part of these costs in the most of projects where this change is not needed. If we discus customer perspective more deeply we can say that he should not pay for that at all because choosing bad API which has to be replaced later on is failure of developers / architects. Refactor your code regularly but only to the point which is needed for adding new features which customer wants otherwise you can hardly be competitive on the market. This of course has some exceptions:

- Customer wants (or architecture demands it for any reason and customer agrees with it) such abstraction. In such case you must count with it and define architecture open for such changes.
- It is hobby or open source project where you can do what you want because it is not constrained by some resources

Now to your problem. If you want such high level abstraction you should not expose entities to your controller. Expose DTOs from the business layer (or even from repositories) and add fields like IsNew, IsModified, IsDeleted to those DTOs. Now your UI is completely separated from the persistence but your architecture is much more complex and there is probably no reason for such complexity - it is over architected. Another way can be simply turning off tracking (add `AsNoTracking()` to each query) and proxy creation on your entities (`context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled`) - lazy loading will not work as well. That's like throwing away most of features persistence frameworks offer to you.

There are also other points of view. I recommend you reading [Ayende's](http://ayende.com/blog/default.aspx) recent posts about repository and his comments to Sharp architecture.

Comment: Just wanted to add that all ORMs also share a load of differences that would be hard to swap out.  

Off the top of my head differences include cascading delete behavior, eager loading behavior, linq behavior ( must do  order before skip in take with ef for example ), stored proc/view behavior, ad-hoc sql behavior, projection behavior even with linq.  The mythical swappable ORM layer doesn't exist. You are in for a lot of work anyway.

Comment: Great answer! Honestly sometimes I just need to bounce this stuff off others to put my mind at ease.

Comment: This is a good point of view for a single app but what if you plan to write multiple applications and they should all use the same basic concepts (and maybe code - aka library). Then things get complicated and you can not just "build what the customer wants" (he doesn't know anyway).

Answer (score 2):

Short answer? You don't. You could turn off EF's tracking and then not worry about it, but that's about it.

If you're going to write your presentation layer with the expectation that changes are being tracked and persisted automatically, then whatever you replace EF with has to do that. You can't swap it out for something that doesn't track and persist changes automatically and just expect things to keep working. That'd be like taking a system that relies on a TCP/IP connection for duplex communication, swapping it to a HTTP connection (which by the nature of HTTP isn't really duplex) and expect things to work the same way. It doesn't.

If you want to be able to swap out your persistence layer for something else and not have to change anything else, then you need to wrap EF (or whatever) in your own custom code to provide the functionality you want. Then you have to provide implementations for anything not provided by whatever you swap to.

This is doable, but it's going to be an awful lot of work for a problem that very rarely actually happens. It's also going to add extra complexity to the project. Ladislav is bang on: it's not worth abstracting this far.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement the repository pattern and plain POCOS if you are concerned about potentially swapping out EF.

There is a great project on Codeplex that goes over Domain Driven design including documentation. Take a look at that.

http://microsoftnlayerapp.codeplex.com/

Comment: That seems to me to be defeating the purpose of persistence ignorance. My controller layer shouldn't care about whether I'm using an ORM or a repository model.

Comment: If the two things don't provide the same functionality, then your controller layer most definitely should care. Something that's automatically tracking and persisting changes requires fundamentally different controller logic from something that doesn't.

Comment: You're correct and as I said you can use plain POCOS and pass those around as DTOs - they should be persistent ignorant. The repository pattern doesn't pigeon hold you to using any particular data access methodology.

Answer (score 0):

Please after reading Microsoft n-layer project, read [ayenede's weblog.](http://ayende.com/blog)
Mr.ayende posted series posts about advantage and disadvantage Microsoft n-layer project.